# Ngrok SSH connection closed by remote host

Tags: ssh, ngrok

I'm using Ngrok to SSH to my remote Ubuntu machine. It seems to be working properly but after a few minutes I get the following error:

```
Connection to 0.tcp.ngrok.io closed by remote host.
Connection to 0.tcp.ngrok.io closed.
```

In my SSH `config` file I have:

```
TCPKeepAlive yes
ServerAliveInterval 30
```

but it does not seem to avoid the problem. What can I do?

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problem as well.
I ran `./ngrok tcp 22` and the issue was that I didn't have a SSH server up and running on port 22 of the local machine.

On Linux, you can check if you ran server by `systemctl status sshd` and run it by `systemctl start sshd`.

Comment: This isn't an answer to the actual issue. He can ssh just fine, the session is being terminated. I'm having the same issue, despite having added 
`TCPKeepAlive yes
ClientAliveInterval 30
ClientAliveCountMax 240`